# Moving buttons in winform board

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to write a code for a simple game of 2048. I've managed to implement functions for moving the buttons in columns and summing them if they're equal, but somehow, only in X ratio. Why aren't they doing the same thing in Y?

Here's the code:

```
bool checkIfMoved; 

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{           
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            checkIfMoved = false;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
                {
                    if ((j != 0) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i, j - 1].Visible == false))
                    {
                        moveButton(i, j, e);
                    }
                    else if ((j != 0) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i, j - 1].Visible == true))
                    {
                        sumButtons(i, j, e);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (checkIfMoved == true)
            {
                GenerateField();
            }
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            checkIfMoved = false;

            for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for (int j = 3; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    if ((j != 3) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i, j + 1].Visible == false))
                    {
                        moveButton(i, j, e);
                    }
                    else if ((j != 3) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i, j + 1].Visible == true))
                    {
                        sumButtons(i, j, e);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (checkIfMoved == true)
            {
                GenerateField();
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                checkIfMoved = false;

                for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 3; j >= 0; j--)
                    {
                        if ((i != 0) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i - 1, j].Visible == false))
                        {
                            moveButton(i, j, e);
                        }
                        else if ((i != 0) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i - 1, j].Visible == true))
                        {
                            sumButtons(i, j, e);
                        }
                    }

                    if (checkIfMoved == true)
                    {
                        GenerateField();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                checkIfMoved = false;

                for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
                    {
                        if ((i != 3) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i + 1, j].Visible == false))
                        {
                            moveButton(i, j, e);                                                
                        }
                        else if ((i != 3) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i + 1, j].Visible == true))
                        {
                            sumButtons(i, j, e);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (checkIfMoved == true)
                {
                    GenerateField();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Now the moving and summing functions:

```
    private void moveButton(int i, int j, KeyEventArgs e)
    {           
        SwitchKey Switch = new SwitchKey(i, j, e);                           
            try
            {

                while (board[Switch.line, Switch.column].Text == "0")
                {
                    board[Switch.line, Switch.column].Text = board[i, j].Text;
                    board[Switch.line, Switch.column].Visible = true;
                    board[i, j].Visible = false;
                    board[i, j].Text = "0";
                    sumButtons(Switch.line, Switch.column, e);
                    checkIfMoved = true;
                    switch(e.KeyCode)
                    {
                        case(Keys.Left):
                            j--;
                            break;
                        case(Keys.Right):
                            j++;
                            break;
                        case(Keys.Up):
                            i--;
                            break;
                        case(Keys.Down):
                            i++;
                            break;
                    }
                    Switch = new SwitchKey(i, j, e);
                }
            }
            catch { }
    }
    private void sumButtons(int i, int j, KeyEventArgs e)
    {           
        SwitchKey Switch = new SwitchKey(i, j, e);
        while ((board[i, j].Text == board[Switch.line,Switch.column].Text))
        {
            int x;
            int y;
            Int32.TryParse(board[i, j].Text, out x);
            Int32.TryParse(board[Switch.line, Switch.column].Text, out y);
            int z = x + y;
            string a = z.ToString();
            board[Switch.line, Switch.column].Text = a;
            board[Switch.line, Switch.column].Visible = true;
            board[i, j].Visible = false;
            board[i, j].Text = "0";

        }
    }
```

and the SwitchKey class:

```
    class SwitchKey
{
    public int line;
    public int column;

    public SwitchKey(int i, int j, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {


        #region Keycode switch
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case (System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Left):
                {
                    column = j-1;
                    line = i;
                    break;
                }
            case (System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Right):
                {
                    column = j + 1;
                    line = i;
                    break;
                }
            case (System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Up):
                {
                    column = j;
                    line = i-1;
                    break;
                }
            case (System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Down):
                {
                    column = j;
                    line = i+1;
                    break;
                }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The game works perfectly when i use left and right keys but doesn't do anything when using up and down. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Debugger is your friend here. TL;DR

Comment: debugger isnt going to help since there arent any bugs. the system just ignores the up and down keys

Comment: wow... debugging is not just for bugs @JimmyHabanero sounds like you're going to be on your own with this one since you are so reluctant to step through your own code.. you wrote it ..you should be able to fix it.. sorry for being `Point Blank` but come on now...

Comment: Ah now it's clear, your if that handles key UP/DOWN is not in the correct level

Comment: @JimmyHabanero If it ignores them due to some UI(other) issue, then create [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates such problem in the shortest possible version. Most people here are [just not interested in debugging walls of the code that is irrelevant to the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216018/how-to-handle-debug-my-code-for-me-questions).

Comment: well it didnt hurt to ask.. im just sitting on this problem whole day and just cant figure out whats wrong. i'm just out of ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misplaced }

Your

```
 else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
```

Is nested inside your

```
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
```

Try this:

```
bool checkIfMoved; 
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{           
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    {

        checkIfMoved = false;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
            {
                if ((j != 0) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i, j - 1].Visible == false))
                {
                    moveButton(i, j, e);
                }
                else if ((j != 0) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i, j - 1].Visible == true))
                {
                    sumButtons(i, j, e);
                }
            }
        }
        if (checkIfMoved == true)
        {
            GenerateField();
        }

    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
        checkIfMoved = false;
        for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = 3; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if ((j != 3) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i, j + 1].Visible == false))
                {
                    moveButton(i, j, e);
                }
                else if ((j != 3) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i, j + 1].Visible == true))
                {
                    sumButtons(i, j, e);
                }
            }
        }
        if (checkIfMoved == true)
        {
            GenerateField();
        }
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        checkIfMoved = false;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 3; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if ((i != 0) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i - 1, j].Visible == false))
                {
                    moveButton(i, j, e);
                }
                else if ((i != 0) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i - 1, j].Visible == true))
                {
                    sumButtons(i, j, e);
                }
            }
            if (checkIfMoved == true)
            {
                GenerateField();
            }
        }
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
    {
        checkIfMoved = false;

        for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
            {
                if ((i != 3) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i + 1, j].Visible == false))
                {
                    moveButton(i, j, e);                                                
                }
                else if ((i != 3) && (board[i, j].Visible == true) && (board[i + 1, j].Visible == true))
                {
                    sumButtons(i, j, e);
                }
            }
        }
        if (checkIfMoved == true)
        {
            GenerateField();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need a close brace here

```
    ....
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
        checkIfMoved = false;
        .... a lot of code
        if (checkIfMoved == true)
        {
            GenerateField();
        }  
    }// <-- here
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
       ...
```